# TypeError: crossobj is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problem loading the carousel at the bottom of this page: http://bucharestcitytour.com/Treasures_of_Romania_Tour#

First I loaded jQuery and fixed most errors that appeared but now I get an error in Firebug's console that says:

```
TypeError: crossobj is null

contentheight[contentID]=crossobj.offsetHeight
```

Tried searching on Google and SO for an answer to this type of problem but couldn't find anything, this is the only similar error that I found [TypeError: arr is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096998/typeerror-arr-is-null) and it doesn't have an answer.

What does that error message means and how can I fix it? Please note that I'm a total beginner when it comes to JS/jQuery.

Update:

Here is the code part:

```
function getInitialSize(contentID,containerID){
    var crossobj=document.getElementById(contentID);
    var crossCobj=document.getElementById(containerID);

    contentheight[contentID]=crossobj.offsetHeight
    contentwidth[contentID]=crossobj.offsetWidth
    containerheight[contentID]=crossCobj.offsetHeight
    containerwidth[contentID]=crossCobj.offsetWidth
    //alert(containerwidth[contentID]);
}
```

For a better understanding you can check out the link with Firebug and it leads you exactly to the line with the problem, that being `contentheight[contentID]=crossobj.offsetHeight`.

Comment: can you show some JS code where you declared `crossobj` ?

Comment: updated to include code

Comment: You are passing `contentID` and/or `containerID` wrong, it's because `getElementById()` returns null and not the DOM object you need. Share the call to this function `getInitialSize()` and we can help you better

Comment: When you are calling the method `getInitialSize` the DOM is not fully loaded. Thats the reason why the element with id `contenty` cannot be found. Please move the calls of `getInitialSize` to an `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` call.

Comment: You are calling getInitialSize('contentz','containerz') from line no 660 in your source code. And FYI there in no html taga with the passed ID's